# How do I configure Ubuntu 16.04 to show my ZFS zvols internal partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux, zvol

I seem to be missing some zvol functionality, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. I had this functionality with these same zpools on an ArchLinux installation. (Migrated the server.)

Ubuntu puts the zvols in `/dev/zvol` and arch mounted them in `/dev`. That's okay, but I don't know what happened to the partitions that are created on the zvol itself:

```
root@nosgoth:/dev/zvol/tank2/vm# fdisk -l tisc
Disk tisc: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 8192 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 8192 bytes / 8192 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0006b0ad

Device Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
tisc1           2048 37109759 37107712 17.7G 83 Linux
tisc2       37109760 41940991  4831232  2.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

On archlinux this would result in devices called `tiscPart0` and `tiscPart1`, and ultimately some `/dev/zd64p1` and `/dev/zd64p2` Since the pretty names are just a symlink to real devices `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 31 21:36 tisc -> ../../../zd64`

These things are also mentioned in ZFS administration guides: [See the EXT4 on ZVOL section](https://pthree.org/2012/12/21/zfs-administration-part-xiv-zvols/).

I'm assuming there's perhaps a udev configuration? I'm not sure what I'm missing, and searches aren't coming up very helpful. How do I get those partitions to show up?

Comment: This is probably best for the [ZFS on Linux mailing lists](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Mailing-Lists).

Comment: I'll give it a go, and see if I can get traction there as well. I'll also post the solution should I find one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just now, on ubuntu 16.04 I did `sudo find /dev` and then created a zvol, and then `sudo find /dev` again, and then created partitions, and then did a final `sudo find /dev` to see what was created at each step along the way. What I found was:

`sudo zfs create -V 8g storage/junkzvol` created `/dev/zvol/storage/junkzvol`

`sudo fdisk /dev/zvol/storage/junkzvol` created `/dev/zvol/storage/junkzvol-part1` and `/dev/zvol/storage/junkzvol-part2`

While I was doing this, I noticed, that the new devices were visible to root, but not visible to me. I required the `sudo` in order to `find` the devices. Tab completion on the command prompt wasn't working for eharvey.

You might just need to use `sudo` for your `ls` and `find` and whatever.

Comment: There must be a difference between creating the partitions from the dom0, and from within the Guest VM installer. No configuration required.

Comment: No difference between creating the paritions on dom0 or from the guest VM. I just needed to `partprobe` on the dom0 so it would be updated with the new partition table information. Then everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the 
kpartx
command. It is able to look into partitioning, create /dev/mapper entries and mount or unmount those.